# Belongs to many associations add foreign keys to source model, SequelizeDatabaseError: column "CategoryID" does not exist

Tags: node.js, postgresql, typescript, sequelize.js

I try to explain my case. I have two models: `Film` and `Category`. They are N:M associations.

migration file `20200123070411-createTables.js`:

```js
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Category', {
      ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Last_Update: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
    await queryInterface.createTable('Language', {
      ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING(20),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Last_Update: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });
    await queryInterface.createTable('Film', {
      ID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true,
        autoIncrement: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      LanguageID: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: 'Language',
          key: 'ID',
        },
        onDelete: 'restrict',
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Title: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Description: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Release_Year: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Rental_Duration: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Rental_Date: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(19, 0),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Length: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Replacement_Cost: {
        type: Sequelize.DECIMAL(19, 0),
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Rating: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Last_Update: {
        type: Sequelize.DATE,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Special_Features: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      Fulltext: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        allowNull: false,
      },
    });

    await queryInterface.createTable(
      'Film_Category',
      {
        FilmID: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          // composite primary key
          primaryKey: true,
          references: {
            model: 'Film',
            key: 'ID',
          },
          onDelete: 'restrict',
        },
        CategoryID: {
          type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
          primaryKey: true,
          references: {
            model: 'Category',
            key: 'ID',
          },
          onDelete: 'cascade',
        },
        Last_Update: {
          type: Sequelize.DATE,
          allowNull: false,
        },
      }
    );
  },

  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Film_Category');
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Film');
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Category');
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Language');
  },
};
```

After executing the db migration, I define models below:

`models/category.ts`:

```js
import { Model, DataTypes, BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../db';
import { Film } from './film_category';

class Category extends Model {
  public ID!: number;
  public Name!: string;
  public Last_Update!: Date;
  public getFilms!: BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin<Film>;
}
Category.init(
  {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(20),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Last_Update: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Category' },
);

export { Category };
```

`models/film.ts`:

```js
import { Model, DataTypes, BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../db';
import { Category } from './film_category';

class Film extends Model {
  public ID!: number;
  public LanguageID!: number;
  public Title!: string;
  public Description!: string;
  public Release_Year!: number;
  public Rental_Duration!: number;
  public Rental_Date!: number;
  public Length!: number;
  public Replacement_Cost!: number;
  public Rating!: number;
  public Last_Update!: Date;
  public Special_Features!: string;
  public Fulltext!: string;
  public getCategories!: BelongsToManyGetAssociationsMixin<Category>;
}
Film.init(
  {
    ID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    LanguageID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: 'Language',
        key: 'ID',
      },
      onDelete: 'restrict',
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Title: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Description: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Release_Year: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Rental_Duration: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Rental_Date: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(19, 0),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Length: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Replacement_Cost: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(19, 0),
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Rating: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Last_Update: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Special_Features: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    Fulltext: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Film' },
);

export { Film };
```

`models/film_category.ts`:

```js
import { Model, DataTypes } from 'sequelize';
import { sequelize } from '../db';
import { Category } from './category';
import { Film } from './film';

class FilmCategory extends Model {
  public FilmID!: number;
  public CategoryID!: number;
  public Last_Update!: Date;
}
FilmCategory.init(
  {
    FilmID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'Film',
        key: 'ID',
      },
      onDelete: 'restrict',
    },
    CategoryID: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      references: {
        model: 'Category',
        key: 'ID',
      },
      onDelete: 'cascade',
    },
    Last_Update: {
      type: DataTypes.DATE,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { sequelize, modelName: 'Film_Category' },
);

export { FilmCategory, Film, Category };
```

`models/index.ts`:

```js
import { Category } from './category';
import { Film } from './film';
import { Language } from './language';
import { FilmCategory } from './film_category';

Category.belongsToMany(Film, { through: FilmCategory });
Film.belongsToMany(Category, { through: FilmCategory });

Language.hasMany(Film);

export { Category, Film, Language, FilmCategory };
```

When I try to call `Film.findByPk(1)`, `sequelize` throw an error:

> SequelizeDatabaseError: column "CategoryID" does not exist

The SQL query generated by `sequelize` of `Film.findByPk(1)` like this:

> Executing (default): SELECT "ID", "LanguageID", "Title", "Description", "Release_Year", "Rental_Duration", "Rental_Date", "Length", "Replacement_Cost", "Rating", "Last_Update", "Special_Features", "Fulltext", "CategoryID" FROM "Film" AS "Film" WHERE "Film"."ID" = 1;

I know when I use `Film.belongsToMany(Category, { through: FilmCategory });`, `sequelize` will add `CategoryID` of target model `Category` to source model `Film`. I expect the film data find by primary key has the same properties as the model schema. This extra `CategoryID` column is the issue.

So I don't want this `CategoryID` column to be added on `Film` model and `FilmID` column to be added on `Category` model. Because `Film` table doesn't have `CategoryID` column and `Category` table doesn't have `FilmID` column in the database. They are connected by the join table `Film_Category`. Is there any way to do this? Or, am I missing something?

Created a minimal reproducible code repo: https://github.com/mrdulin/node-sequelize-examples/tree/master/src/db

Answer (score 0):

Should work if you explicitly define the 'through' table in the association, like so:

```
    Film.belongsToMany(Category, 
        {
         through: FilmCategory, 
         foreignKey: 'FilmID',  
         otherKey: 'CategoryID' 
        });
```

It's possible the problems may occurs because you're using ID rather than Id, but that is just speculation...

HTH

Comment: strange.  You said << when I use `Film.belongsToMany(Category, { through: FilmCategory });, sequelize` will add `CategoryID` of target model `Category` to source model `Film`>> but this does not occur for me.  I use mySql but also, my `through` table has a single int PK (and two foreign keys), rather than a compound primary key.  Might be worth a try, if it's not too much work.